# Import google chrome bookmarks as individual bookmark with tag in Evernote

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, evernote

I know we can import all google chrome bookmark by exporting them in one single html file and then just dragging that file into Evernote as a single note. However, then there is just single note without any tags.

What I want to do is to import these google chrome bookmark as an individual items bookmark note with tags into my Evernote. So that I can search it by tag name.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you looking for multiple notes created in one notebook that are tagged the same or a different structure?

Comment: tags should be unique across multiple notes if possible